How to map element ID to DTO object field?
I'm trying to map the elementId value in the DTO class field in Spring Data, but the mapping doesn't happen. If I change the field name to something other than id, the mapping is performed.
    @Query("""
        MATCH (s:Skill {id:$skillId})-[r]-(ss:Synonym)
        RETURN elementId(ss) AS id,
               ss.synonym AS synonym,
               ss.autocomplete AS autocomplete
    """)
    Collection<SynonymResponse> findSynonymsBySkill(String skillId);

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.*;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class SynonymResponse {
    /** ID. */
    private String id;
    /** Tittle. */
    private String synonym;
    /** Show in autocomplete. */
    private boolean autocomplete;
}

@Node({"Synonym"})
public class Synonym {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty(
        required = true
    )
    @Property("synonym")
    private String title;
    private boolean autocomplete;


I tried changing the name field in the DTO, but when the name is different, the display occurs.

I can produce this solution way shown below
By using @JsonProperty, it can help clarify which JSON property maps to which field in SynonymResponse
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class SynonymResponse {
    @JsonProperty("id") // Ensure this matches what you want to map
    private String id;
    private String synonym;
    private boolean autocomplete;
}


That's what I decided in the end. I have a suspicion that the alias name intersects with the node field name and that's why the mapping doesn't work.
